# Formatting a table in CSS

Tags: php, css, html-table

I have my html table, and I want to specify the height of each cell, the font, the font colour and well various things... before I was getting around it with inline styles but I want to put it into my CSS but can't do it! I have added a class name and referenced in correctly but for some reason no attributes of the table will talk to the CSS. This is the only page element with this problem:

```
echo "<table class='blogtable'><tr>";

    echo "</tr>\n";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{

    $usn1 = $row['username'];
    $tml1 = $row['timeleft'];
    $bge1 = $row['blogentry'];
    $bge2 = substr($bge1,0,50);
    $tml2 = substr($tml1,0,11);

    echo "<tr class='blogrow'>";



        echo "<td class='bloglink'>";
        echo "<a class='bloglink' href='blog.php' >".$bge2."...</a>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td class='blogunderline'>";
        echo "By";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td class='blogunderline'>";
        echo $usn1;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td class='blogunderline'>";
        echo " - ";
        echo "<td class='blogunderline'>";
        echo $tml2;
        echo "</td>";



    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";



a.bloglink{
    color: #696969;
    text-decoration: none;

}

table.blogtable{

    font-family: arial; 
    color:#696969; 
    font-size: 11pt; 
    line-height: 28px;
}

td.blogunderline{

    border-bottom-style:dotted; 
    border-width: 0.5px;

}
```

but the html says.... no thank you!

```
tr.blogrow{
     border-bottom:solid 0.5px; 
     text-decoration:none;

}
```

edit: I am embarrassed to say but I had two CSS files open, one on the home server and one on the hdd, I was editing the wrong one! sorry for the trouble!

Comment: also, why wont the table inherit the styles from the div it is in!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tr.blogrow {border-bottom:solid 0.5px} has no color attached to it. Neither does td.blogunderline.

Your CSS won't reference itself 'twice'.  When you define tr.blogrow, drop the tr, and just use .blogrow (same with your other CSS items  table.blogtable and td.blogunderline)

```
echo "<table class='blogtable'><tr>";

                echo "</tr>\n";

            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {

                $usn1 = $row['username'];
                $tml1 = $row['timeleft'];
                $bge1 = $row['blogentry'];
                $bge2 = substr($bge1,0,50);
                $tml2 = substr($tml1,0,11);

                echo "<tr class='blogrow'>";



                    echo "<td class='bloglink'>";
                    echo "<a class='bloglink' href='blog.php' >".$bge2."...</a>";
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td class='blogunderline'>";
                    echo "By";
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td class='blogunderline'>";
                    echo $usn1;
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td class='blogunderline'>";
                    echo " - ";
                    echo "<td class='blogunderline'>";
                    echo $tml2;
                    echo "</td>";



                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";



.bloglink{
color: #696969;
text-decoration: none;

}

.blogtable{

font-family: arial; 
color:#696969; 
font-size: 11pt; 
line-height: 28px;
}

.blogunderline{

border-bottom:dotted 1px blue

}
 .blogrow{ border-bottom:solid 1px blue; text-decoration:none;

}
```

Remember that you must use whole pixels, not half pixels, that you must define a color for your border, and that your `<tr>` styles will override your `<td>` border style (`<td class="blogunderline">` will NOT apply a blue dotted border-bottom.

Comment: thanks for the responce, but the table isnt taking on ANY of the properties from the css.... the a tag is still underlined and purple and its all still in the default times new roman, 10pt etc

Comment: and still no underline on the table and all black.. it all works with in line css but not this... the stylesheet is linked as every other attribute of the page is correct

Comment: Please update the OP with the changes you have made.

Comment: I have updated my answer to help you get this working.

Comment: thank you for the responce, I am embaressed to say but I had two css files open, one on the home server and one on the hdd, i was editing the wrong one! sorry for the trouble!

Comment: No problem, I just did the EXACT same thing on a file myself (after trying to get someone here on SO to help me, discovered it myself!)